# Pros/cons of having two kids' birthdays on the same date

Tags: pregnancy, personality, birthday

My wife is now going to discuss possibility of induced labour with her doctor and we might need to pick up the date for delivery of our second daughter.

Our first daughter is turning 4 in couple of weeks and we were thinking about setting their birthday on the same date. Another option is to have them separated by a week or a few days.

This is an important decision with life-time consequences, and I am not quite sure what implications I should consider first. Perhaps anyone with similar experience in the past could share their view.

These are my only kids so far (two daughters) and the only reason of having them born on same date is it may somehow make them feel unusual and stand out in a crowd in future. I am quite sure this is not a very good reason. On the other hand, I definitely don't want to do it only to simplify my life and making future birthday's party planning easier for me, I think they will have them celebrated separately anyway.

Is it better to have birthdays separated by only a few days ?

I would very much appreciate your feedback, perhaps someone with similar experience could share their thoughts.
Thanks!

**Update** after reading answers/comments:
Thanks a lot to all of you, it gave me opportunity to look at it from different perspectives which was the reason I asked the question.

I and my wife are feeling more inclined now towards *separate* dates for B-day.
One extra reason for that are in details I left out initially : 
this is the first time our 4-year daughter is consciously anticipating her birthday party. We are expats, recently moved to a new country and she is still socializing, so we feel almost obliged to have a party(actually two) with her new schoolmates as well as one with her new friends speaking her native language. 
The important part : she and we thought her mother presence at the party could be very important and I think this will drive our final decision on the new baby B-day date.
As expressed in answers/comments : our main concern again is health condition, so we will rely on doctor's suggestions, otherwise I see it as they will be separated by a week or so (ideally having delivery before the event for 4-year old).

I can post an update in a month or so with the final results in case anyone interested, otherwise, thanks again to all of you. I upvoted all answers as they've been very helpful.
I have troubles picking one as accepted though as most have a point that I agree with.

Comment: @AdamDavis not a duplicate, I ask about girls and in your link its about boys' B-days! Seriously, I wasn't convinced by the answer in your link and decided to ask my question.